# Python local UDP client won't accept messages from local server when using hostname

Tags: python, sockets, udp

I'm following the book "Foundations of Python Network Programming". It has an example of a UDP server/client that can send messages to each other. Here is what it looks like

```
import socket, sys
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

MAX = 65535
PORT = 1060

if 2<= len(sys.argv) <=3 and sys.argv[1] == 'server':
    interface = sys.argv[2] if len(sys.argv) > 2 else ''
    s.bind((interface, PORT))
    print('Listening at {}'.format(s.getsockname()))
    while True:
        data, address = s.recvfrom(MAX)
        print('The client at {} says: {}'.format(address, repr(data)))
        msg = 'Your data was {} bytes'.format(len(data))
        s.sendto(msg.encode('utf-8'), address)

elif len(sys.argv)==3 and sys.argv[1]=='client':
    hostname = sys.argv[2]
    s.connect((hostname, PORT))
    print('Client socket name is {}'.format(s.getsockname()))
    s.send(b'This is another message')
    s.settimeout(5.0)
    data = s.recv(MAX)
    print('The server says', repr(data)) code here
```

I start the server on my local machine:

```
python listing2-2.py server
Listening at ('0.0.0.0', 1060)
```

Then I run my client

```
python listing2-2.py client 127.0.0.1    
Client socket name is ('127.0.0.1', 59535)
The server says b'Your data was 23 bytes'
```

And everything is fine. I can use localhost and that works too. But if I use my hostname

```
python listing2-2.py client <myhostname>
Client socket name is ('127.0.0.1', 45677)
```

and the client times out. The server receives the message from the client (I see the output "This is another message" on the server side), but the client seems to be refusing the message from the server. I'm trying to understand why.

Comment: Just tried your code as it is without any changes. Works fine with the host name. I am on Win10 & Python 3.6. I guess the problem is somehow related to the local network your PC is located in.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 18.04. I've tried it while connecting two different laptops on two different routers. Not sure why it isn't working....

Comment: I am using macOS High Sierra 10.13.6.  The program works fine, as is.  Note that on my mac the output of "hostname" ends with the .local domain.  If I run your program using the hostname without the .local domain, it does not work.  Try using the hostname with the .local domain if you have not already done so.